# Ubuntu installation gets stuck at "[sda] Synchronising SCSI cache"

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, scsi

I've tried changing USBs, manual partitioning and the automatic one, turning secure boot on and off and pretty much everything I could think of but the installation always gets stuck after the reboot required for completion at "[sda] [Synchronising SCSI cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqXwp.jpg)". I've read this has maybe something to do with graphics drivers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work, the problem indeed were the graphics drivers. I added 'nomodeset' to grub boot options to boot into the live USB and then started the installation from there, did the same thing once more after the installation to boot into Ubuntu and it worked, from where then I installed nvidia drivers. Rebooted, and everything seems to be fine now so far.

Comment: It seems like a semi-known bug and you manage to fix it. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/apw7kh/nvidia_problems_when_installing_ubuntu_or_running/